# Какими способами можно добавить заголовки?

Tags: python, django, http

В `view` я использую `JsonResponse` для возвращения на фронт ответа в виде JSON:

```
def dates_index(request):
    dates = Date.objects.all()   
    dates_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', dates)
    return JsonResponse(dates_serialized, safe=False)
```

Проблема в том, что я хотел бы с этим ответом вернуть некоторый заголовок. Правильно ли я рассуждаю?

1. Если использовать `HttpResponse`, то возвращаемые заголовки добавляются примерно так:

   ```
   HttpResponse['hhh'] = 'value'  
   return HttpResponse
   ```
2. Но существует второй способ возвращать заголовки (он более современный). Нужно создать middleware и прописать его в файле `settings`. Таким образом к ответам из любых view будет добавляться заголовок из ранее созданного middleware.
3. У `JsonResponse` в отличие от `HttpResponse` нет возможности добавлять возвращаемые заголовки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) - это субкласс `HttpResponse`, поэтому у него есть все те же возможности:

```
response = JsonResponse(dates_serialized, safe=False)
response['hhh'] = 'value'
return response
```